# Cannot get my head around this web-pack path error

Tags: module, path, webpack, sass-loader

My project structure is as follows:

[image]

I have the following webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/resources",
    entry: "./js/entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

and open up my entry.js file with

```
require('./style.scss');
```

I understand this specific arrangement might not be working, but i have been trying different permutations and setups and configurations for over an hour and just can't seem to get webpack to find my .scss file.

Can someone please tell me how the webpack config file should be set up in my case?

Cheers.

edit,

trying to go up two levels in my require,

```
require('../../scss/style.scss')
```

still gives me,

[image]

Similarly for

```
require('../scss/style.scss');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel like a complete idiot, after renaming files and folders numerous times and trying different permutations of my require statement, I noticed the error seems to constantly state

```
Can't resolve 'style' in ...
```

Turns out i had not installed style-loader and css-loader into my project having though they were bundled with the sass-loader. (it's actually noted on the npm page), running

```
npm install css-loader style-loader -D
```

in my project directory solved the issue.

Still, thanks for your suggestions, and I hope this might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the require statement

```
require('./style.scss');
```

It will search for your style file inside the `resources/js` directory in reference to your `entry.js` file try requiring your style using this:

```
require('../scss/style.scss');
```

Try to use `path` module for resolving the context path:

```
var path = require('path');
...
context: path.resolve("resources"),
...
```

Let me know if the problem resolved.

Comment: Nope, still gives me, Can't Resolve 'style' in '/var/www/resources', i feel like i'm missing something really basic

Comment: I feel like there is something wrong in resolving your context path. Try using the path module instead to resolve your path.
I'll update that to my answer, let me know what you get